# how to find a - LIMIT

Tags: calculus

I am a student in computer science - second year. I study calculus
I tried to solve the question a few hours but I'm not sure how to solve it exactly.

[image]

i have a limit when x equals to 1

Answer (score 2):

For limit to exist since denominator is 0 hence numerator should be 0.
Hence you get a =1.
Now question is $ \lim_{x\to 1}(\frac{(x+3)(x-1)}{(x+2)(x-1)}) $ $\\$ $ \lim_{x\to 1}(\frac{(x+3)}{(x+2)}) \;= \frac{4}{3} $

Answer (score 1):

The limit exists only when  $a=1$. In that case the limit is $\frac  4 3$ by L'Hopitals' Rule. You can also see this by factoring out $x-1$ from numerator and denominator.

When $a>1$ or $a<1$ the left hand and right hand limits are different so the limit does not exist.

Comment: how you get that?

Answer (score 0):

*Another way to do it.*

First, let $x=y+1$ to make
$$\frac{x^2+2 a x-a-2}{x^2+x-2}=\frac{y^2+2 (a+1) y+a-1}{y (y+3)}$$ Now, perform the long division to get
$$\frac{y^2+2 (a+1) y+a-1}{y (y+3)}=\frac{a-1}{3 y}+\frac{5 a+7}{9}+\frac{2-5a}{27} y+\cdots$$ So, to have a limit, $a=1$ and the limit is ???

Comment: why you assume that x=y+1

Comment: @Haham. It is simpler to look at the limit when $y \to 0$ (and to perform the long division or Taylor series). Small trick.